# SQL To Return Data set Where Multiple Conditions Are Met

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following MS-Access table:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ colPartNo ║ colOperation ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ A            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ B            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 1         ║ C            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2         ║ B            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 2         ║ C            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 3         ║ C            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 3         ║ D            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 3         ║ E            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 4         ║ A            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 4         ║ B            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 4         ║ C            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 4         ║ D            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 5         ║ A            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 5         ║ B            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 5         ║ C            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 6         ║ B            ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ 6         ║ C            ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

What I'm trying to do and can't seem to wrap my head around, is to return a dataset that contains only the distinct part numbers where the part number has operations A, B, & C.  The part number may have other operations but it MUST have all three of these.  I can get a distinct list of the part numbers but it includes parts that do not have all three of the operations, using the statement below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblPart_Info.Part_No, tblPart_Info.Operation
FROM tblPart_Info
WHERE (((tblPart_Info.Operation)="A" Or (tblPart_Info.Operation)="B" Or (tblPart_Info.Operation)="C"))
ORDER BY tblPart_Info.Part_No;
```

The dataset that I'm looking to get back would be part numbers 1, 4, & 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT pi.Part_No, tblPart_Info.Operation
FROM tblPart_Info as pi
GROUP BY pi.Part_No
HAVING SUM(IIF(pi.Operation = "A", 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(pi.Operation = "B", 1, 0)) > 0 AND
       SUM(IIF(pi.Operation = "C", 1, 0)) > 0;
```

This returns the part numbers.  If you want the original rows, use `JOIN`, `IN`, or `EXISTS` to connect this to the original table.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

After making a few changes to the code you provided, I was able to get what I was looking for :)